# Ruby SocketError Handing

Tags: ruby, http, crash

In Ruby none of the error handling that I do seems to take any effect. For example in this function.

```html
def http (uri)
  url = URI.parse(uri)
  if Addressable::url.host
    if url.scheme=='https'
      response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, use_ssl: true, verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|
        http.get url.request_uri, 'User-Agent' => 'MyLib v1.2'
      end
    elsif url.scheme=='http'
      begin
        http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
        response = http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.request_uri))
      rescue
        response.body = "lol"
      end
    end
  else
    response.body = "lol"
  end
  return response.body
end
```

Regardless of the error handling, the code would still crash and give me error on the line right after **begin**.
I know that the url host is not valid, but is the error handling not supposed to fix it?

> `initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)

Comment: what is the url u gave

Comment: It is any invalid host, for example "egdsd"

Comment: i dont get the same error what you specified

Comment: i get the error ``NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass`` since response is nil due to rescue